# Evaluation functions with lower and upper limit ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, evaluation, numerical-value

How do I find the numerical value of y at 0 and also at 1. Here is my code. I appreciate any help.

```
    ϵ = 10^-4; 
R = Rationalize[1.5472, 0];
    sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 3 y'[r]/r == Sinh[y[r]], 
        y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 32001/40]}, {y, y'}, 
        {r, ϵ, R}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
    ff = FindRoot[Last[sol[y0]][R], {y0, -12.25, -11.}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the singularity problems near `r==0`!
Change the boundarie conditions to  `y[R]==0,y'[R]==ys`

```
R = Rationalize[1.5472, 0];
Clear[ys];
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{r y''[r] + 3 y'[r] == r Sinh[y[r]], 
y[R] == 0, y'[R] == ys,WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 32001/40]}, y, {r, 0, R},{ys} ,Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

and force the solution to fullfill `Y'[ys][0]==0`

```
ys=ys/. NMinimize[ Y'[ys][0]^2, ys][[2]]
(* 0.674335*)
```

The functionvalues evaluate to

```
{Y[ys][0] ,Y[ys][1]} 
(*{-2008.16, -0.764241}*)
```

at `r==0` and `r==1`

Hopefully that's what you're looking for!